# Is the syntax for my vector<string> wrong?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class with a vector of items that I am adding into the player's inventory. When I compile my project, I end up with an error relating to my vector but have no idea what could be causing this error. Do I need to use char variables instead of a string?

**Player.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "player.h"
using namespace std;

void Player::AddItem(string item)
{

        items.push_back(item);


}

void Player::UseItem(string item)
{

        if(HasItem(item))
        {
                items.pop_back();
        }


}
```

**Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Player
{

        private:
                int row;
                int col;
                int moves;
                std::vector<std::string> items();

        public:
                Player();
                int GetRow();
                int GetCol();
                void SetPosition(int row, int col);
                void AddItem(std::string item);
                bool HasItem(std::string item);
                void UseItem(std::string item);
                int GetMoveCount();
                void IncrementMoves();





};


#endif
```

**The error I am receiving:**

```
player.cpp: In member function ‘void Player::AddItem(std::__cxx11::string)’:
player.cpp:49:2: error: invalid use of member function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > Player::items()’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  items.push_back(item);
  ^~~~~
player.cpp: In member function ‘void Player::UseItem(std::__cxx11::string)’:
player.cpp:72:3: error: invalid use of member function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > Player::items()’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
   items.pop_back();
   ^~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: player.o] Error 1
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
std::vector<std::string> items();
```

declares a private function called `items` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Change it to

```
std::vector<std::string> items;
```

---

Your error message

```
player.cpp:49:2: error: invalid use of member function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > Player::items()’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
```

Is pretty descriptive on this. It says you have a member function called `items()` and thinks you might be calling it wrong.

Comment: Thank you John. If I am understanding this right.... if I am not taking any arguments in for a vector. The "()" is not necessary. Correct?

Comment: Correct. If a class `T` has a default constructor, you can always construct an object like `T t;`